# How to pass methods and objects directly into a block?

Tags: ruby

For example, in FactoryGirl, it allows you to do something like

```
factory :user, :class => User do
  sequence :username do |n|
    "blahblah#{n}"
  end
end
```

I've looked through the source code at https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl but can't seem to figure out how they are achieving this (it loks like it's some type of proxy?). That is, how is it we are able to access the `sequence` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval).

This means that inside the block `self` (and thus the object `sequence` is called on) isn't what it would otherwise be (probably the top level object in this case) but the object that `instance_eval` was called on (in this case an object that implements the constructs of the factory girl syntax.

It's often used with DSLs (another example is the routes.rb file in rails >= 3) because without it you'd have to do something like

```
factory ... do |f|
  f.sequence ...
end
```

which tend to distract from the DSL.

One tiny example illustrating its effects

```
foo = "123456"
foo.instance_eval do
  length
end
#=> 6
```

With a 'normal' block this would have raised an error, because the top level object has no `length` method, but because `instance_eval` is used length is called on the string instead.